# Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is my first time trying to code so i'm really not sure if this code is even written using the correct methods. Hope someone can help me achieve this If Else coding.

This is my current code:

```
Sub Categorisation()

    For Each Category In Range("A3", "C3", "E3", "I3", "M3", "Q3")

        If Not IsEmpty(Range("A3").Value) Then
            Call Cornersonly_lengthwise_rownumbers

        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("C3").Value) Then
            Call Cornersonly_breadthwise_rownumbers

        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("E3").Value) Then
            Call Cornerscentre_lengthwise_rownumbers

        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("I3").Value) Then
            Call Cornerscentre_breadthwise_rownumbers

        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("M3").Value) Then
            Call Cornerscentreedges_lengthwise_rownumbers

        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range("Q3").Value) Then
            Call Cornerscentreedges_breadthwise_rownumbers

        End If

    Next Category

End Sub
```

Comment: Do your called functions have arguments? If so, you need to write them. Also, you are only checking the first one if it's true, the others won't be evaluated.

Comment: I think your function ```Cornersonly_lengthwise_rownumbers``` needs an parameter? Maybe ```Cornersonly_lengthwise_rownumbers(Range("A3"))```

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying the first condition if it's empty, will skip the others. If you want to check all your statements you need to do this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Categorisation()


    'ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook containing the code.
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ChangeThis")
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("A3")) Then Cornersonly_lengthwise_rownumbers 'arguments (comma separated)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("C3")) Then Cornersonly_breadthwise_rownumbers 'arguments (comma separated)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("E3")) Then Cornerscentre_lengthwise_rownumbers 'arguments (comma separated)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("I3")) Then Cornerscentre_breadthwise_rownumbers 'arguments (comma separated)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("M3")) Then Cornerscentreedges_lengthwise_rownumbers 'arguments (comma separated)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range("Q3")) Then Cornerscentreedges_breadthwise_rownumbers 'arguments (comma separated)
    End With

End Sub
```

In case your called functions have arguments, you need to feed them when called. Also you should fully reference your ranges (a `With` block is an easy way because you only need to use the "." in front of the range)

Comment: You check every category in each iteration, so you check each item 6 times. Is this really necessary? Why not `If Not IsEmpty(Category) Then...`?

Comment: You are actually right @KostasK. the loop is not necessary... I could get ride of the loop and check all the conditions once.